# error_log preventing echo display

Tags: php, error-handling

I'm trying to send myself an email with detailed error info and then display a generic error message to the user. Unfortunately it only displays a white page every time the `error_log` function gets used. I tried using `die('message');` and `echo 'message'; die();` as well as placing them before and after the `error_log()`. Any help would be appreciated. Heres the code I'm using to test. All constants have been defined.

```php
    function onError($e_number, $e_message, $e_file, $e_line, $e_vars) {
        $message = "An error occured in script '$e_file' on line $e_line:\n$e_message.\n";
        $message .= "<pre>" . print_r(debug_backtrace(), 1) . "</pre>\n";
        $message .= "<pre>" . print_r($e_vars, 1) . "</pre>\n";

        if (!LIVE) { echo '<div class="alert alert-danger">' . nl2br($message) . '</div>'; }
        else {
            $headers = "From: errors@" . DOMAIN . "\r\n";
            $headers .= "Subject: ECOM1: ERROR!\r\n";
            $headers .= "To: " . CONTACT_EMAIL . "\r\n";
            $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
            $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n";
            error_log($message, 1, CONTACT_EMAIL, $headers);
            echo '<div class="alert alert-danger>A system error has occured. We apologize for any inconvenience.</div>';
        }
        return true;
    }

    set_error_handler('onError');
    trigger_error('Error test');
```

Comment: Your code runs fine for me locally which suggests a problem in your environment.  Are you able to send emails with PHP?  As Mario has suggested, ensure you have error_reporting turned on with display_errors set to true, and debug the error_log function in isolation without your custom error handler.

Comment: Please try my code and let me know.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you get a white page probably is because the PHP settings prevent any error output. If you can't change the `php.ini` settings, you can try using `.htaccess` to enable error output:

```
php_flag display_startup_errors on
php_flag display_errors on
php_flag html_errors on
php_flag  log_errors on
php_value error_log  /writable/path/domain/error.log
```

Depending on the system you use, please note that you might need to create the file `error.log` and make it writable.

If this doesn't work you can try enabling error loggin in PHP aswell:

```
error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
```

Answer (score 0):

you may want to look at placing your code that might fail inside a try catch and email on the catch and display the message.  Here is the documentation for exception handling it might help to handle this a little better.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php

Answer (score 0):

Please try my code. It works for me

```
<?php
define('LIVE', true);
define('DOMAIN', 'email.com');
define('CONTACT_EMAIL', 'email@gmail.com');

function onError($e_number, $e_message, $e_file, $e_line, $e_vars) {
    $message = "An error occured in script '$e_file' on line $e_line:\n$e_message.\n";
    $message .= "<pre>" . print_r(debug_backtrace(), 1) . "</pre>\n";
    $message .= "<pre>" . print_r($e_vars, 1) . "</pre>\n";

    if(!LIVE) {
        echo '<div class="alert alert-danger">' . nl2br($message) . '</div>';
    } else {
        $headers = "From: errors@" . DOMAIN . "\r\n";
        $headers .= "Subject: ECOM1: ERROR!\r\n";
        $headers .= "To: " . CONTACT_EMAIL . "\r\n";
        $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
        $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n";
        error_log($message, 1, CONTACT_EMAIL, $headers);
        return null;
    }
    return true;
}
$old_error_handler = set_error_handler('onError');

if($old_error_handler == null) {
    echo "<div class='alert alert-danger'>A system error has occured. We apologize for any inconvenience.</div>";
}
```